# Changing orientation clears notification drawer

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Rotating the phone while the notification drawer is open, will clear the list.

Comment: Confirmed on 1.0.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.23, thanks!