# Loading my own question fails

Tags: bug, android-app

I just posted [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223898/changing-orientation-clears-notification-drawer). After posting it, I got the "error loading question" message. When I tried to open the question from the **Active questions** list, I got the same error.

After posting this question, it worked fine and the previous question is now accessible as well.

Comment: It seems that happens when you are on another SE site  while posting here